# Как программно сделать клик по нескольким блокам?

Tags: javascript

Есть блоки с классом button, их много. Нужно программно нажимать по ним, желательно на чистом js.

Пробовал так на jquery: `$('.button').each(function() {this.click();})`

Но пишет в консоли:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).each is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может у вас документ к этому времени ещё не готов? Заверните в `ready`. Как пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($('.button'), function(index, value){
      alert($(value).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="button">
1
</p>
<p class="button">
2
</p>
```

Без jquery:

```js
// здесь все айтемы
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i){
 // например, чтоб вывести внутренности блока, выводим innerHTML
 console.log(items[i].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p class="button">
1
</p>
<p class="button">
2
</p>
```

Для кнопок что-то такое:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('.button');
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++)
  btns[i].click();
```

P.S. для IE9+ использовать `getElementsByClassName`, для IE8+ `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Мне бы это в консоль вставлять. Вот это пишет,если этот код вставить: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined. Ведь jquery работает в консоли браузера?

Comment: @IvanZ а jquery на странице подключен? jquery работает, если подключен.

Comment: @IvanZ прям на этой странице можете вставить в консоль `$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($('.container'), function(index, value){
      alert($(value).html());
  });
});` чтоб убедиться.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }. Значит нету?

Comment: @IvanZ это на что ошибка и где?

Comment: На $.each($('.container'), function(index, value){ alert($(value).html()); }); }); в консоли пишет Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: @IvanZ вы код не полностью скопировали.

Comment: Да,спасибо. Jquery не работает.  Поэтому я и ищу js чистый желательно

Comment: @IvanZ обновил ответ

Comment: Cпасибо за отклик

Comment: @IvanZ рад был помочь.

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
  buttons[i].click();
```